# How can I pass the socketio object from Flask's app.py to a views module in Python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

In my `app.py`, I do:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views.SOMETHING)
socketio = SocketIO(app, ...)
```

I need to use this `socketio` object, or more specifically, its `socketio.emit` method, to talk to clients.

I need to do this from multiple Python modules, like my `views` module, and some modules that define some background threads.

When I'm starting my background threads, it's pretty easy to pass the `socketio` object to them, but I can't figure out how to make this object accessible in my `views` module where all my views are defined.

The only thing I can think of is to have a `global_vars` module that I store the `socketio` object on, which can be imported from multiple Python modules, but I've heard that that's bad practice.

Is there a better way to pass my `socketio` object to my `views` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do `from app import socketio` but make sure that the file that you are importing socketio in is imported into app.py after socketio has been set.